# This server version is not supported. Only servers up to Microsoft SQL Server 2012 are supported

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have SQL Server 2014, VS 2012 and VS 2013. Both VS are ultimate versions. I can not access SQL server from either VS.

Example:

1. Open VS. From Tools menu, select "Create Database". Enter SQL Server name, select a database (all the DBs are listed OK). Click on Test connection button. Connection is OK.

Now when I click the OK button, I get the following error.

> Unable to add data connection. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral....... The system cannot find the file specified.

2. From VS, Server Explorer, right click on Data Connections, "Create a new SQL Server database". Enter Server name, enter new database name. Error message appears:

   > This server version is not supported. Only servers up to Microsoft SQL Server 2012 are supported.

Comment: Issue resolved. I had uninstalled SQL Server 2012, however some parts of SqlServer did not get uninstalled (Native client, etc.). After uninstalling everything that had to do with SQL Server 2012 and reinstalling both SQL server 2014 and VS 2013, everything woks. Only to wasted a few days!!!.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this once:

1. Go to Sql Sever Configuration  Manager
2. Then SQL Server Network Configuration -->Protocols for SQL Server
3. Then Named pipes --> Rc Properties
4. Copy the Pipe Name.

   [image]
5. then go to Visual Studio--> Server Explorer-->Data Connection-->Rc Add Connection

   [image]
6. Then Paste the Copied Pipe Name in Server name
7. Test the Connection.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Server Explorer (View > Server Explorer)
2. Right click on Data Connection
3. Click "Add Connection"
4. Fill Server name
5. Fill database name
6. press "OK"